# Changes in code does not appear after making pull from git repository

Tags: eclipse, git, pull

I'm working with Git in Eclipse, so every time when I tried to pull my repository the changes from my last commit does not appear in project's code. What have I missed?

Comment: Did you refresh the eclipse project?

Comment: Yes, I have. Also tried to restart eclipse but it does not helped

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it with merging the remote and local branch with reducing conflicts by remote side.